# Google Cloud function - how to authenticate while calling Google App Engine

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-authentication, google-app-engine-python

We have an application in App Engine Standard Python 2.7. We also have a Cloud Function in this project.

We would like to do a HTTP POST request to one of the resources in the App Engine application. Currently we have the following code in Cloud Functions

```py
url = "https://project-name.appspot.com/urlidentifier"

data_obj = {
    'sample' : 'data'
}

data_json = json.dumps(data_obj)
data_encode = urllib.parse.urlencode(data_json).encode("utf-8")

req =  request.Request(url, data=data_encode) # this will make the method "POST"
resp = request.urlopen(req)
```

Application in Python 2.7 is authenticated using Firebase user authentication. Please see [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-cookies#verify_session_cookie_and_check_permissions) for details.

Our question - how do we enforce authentication of the application's resource when the HTTP POST is initiated by the Cloud Function (instead of the user). The application resource (https://project-name.appspot.com/urlidentifier) is a function in the project. Can we use service accounts? If yes, how do we do this?

Both the Cloud Function and the application belong to the same project.

Answer (score 0):

You can authenticate via the function's existing [service identity](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/securing/service-identity), see:

https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/authenticating/service-to-service

(This documentation is for Cloud Run, but the pattern is the same for Cloud Functions. You'll need to give the App Engine invoker role to the service account for the function instead).

Comment: With IAP, I think that you have to use this audience pattern when you generate the JWT token: `<PROJECT_NUMBER>-<HASH>.apps.googleusercontent.com`. Have a try and let us know!

Comment: How do we secure Project 1 Application? Currently, the authentication is based on Firebase user authentication. The application is not secured by IAP. Can we have IAP for just one resource - https://project-name.appspot.com/urlidentifier? Is our understanding/approach wrong?

Comment: Project 1 Application is authenticated using Firebase using this  https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-cookies#verify_session_cookie_and_check_permissions . Now we have a resource  project-name.appspot.com/urlidentifier that needs to be accessed by a service account (not a user account). How do we secure  project-name.appspot.com/urlidentifier?